# What is the earliest my warlock can gain access to the Nondetection spell, preferably without multiclassing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, optimization, warlock

For mostly thematic reasons, I would like to eventually get my dwarven warlock access to the spell [*nondetection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/nondetection) (she's sneaky, and will hopefully get access to some sort of invisibility soon). It's preferable that she can cast the spell herself (i.e. with a spell slot), but I'm aware there might be other options (items etc?).

Her patron is a Great Old One, and she will eventually enter into the Pact of the Tome. Nondetection is not on the warlock list, it's not an invocation and Mystic Arcanum only draws on warlock spells anyway.

Her stats are: Str 8, Dex 14, Con 16, Int 12, Wis 8, Cha 17.

---

The easiest route I can see is to multiclass into bard up to level 5, and five non-warlock levels seem like a really big investment without a major reflavouring of the bard class to fit the character.

Are there any other options? If so, what's the earliest I can get access to that spell?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Unless you want be a deep gnome, or happen to be in a Ravnica or Eberron campaign, you need to work with your DM.

No spellcasting class gets access to 3rd level spells earlier than 5th level. There are three character options that can provide access to *nondetection* without having to multi class for it. The Svirfneblin Magic feat available to deep gnomes at 4th level allows you to cast *nondetection* at will. Additionally, the Dimir Operative background from *Guildmaster’s Guide to Ravnica* adds it to your spell list, as does being a Mark of Detection half elf (Eberron race).

Given these things, I would just recommend asking your DM if you can add it to your spell list. The *Dungeon Master’s Guide* gives some guidance for this:

> Modifying a class’s spell list usually has little effect on a character’s power but can change the flavor of a class significantly. In your world, paladins might not swear their oaths to ideals, but instead swear fealty to powerful sorcerers. To capture this story concept, you could build a new paladin spell list with spells meant to protect their masters, drawn from the sorcerer or wizard lists. Suddenly, the paladin feels like a different class.
>
> Be cautious when changing the warlock spell list. Since warlocks regain their spell slots after a short rest, they have the potential to use certain spells more times in a day than other classes do.

I don’t think this change will be an issue for warlocks, as there are already official character options that add *nondetection* to the warlock spell list, and one that lets you cast it at will.

The only non-artifact magic item providing the desired protection against divination is the Amulet of Proof against Detection and Location, and since magic item acquisition is totally within the purview of the DM, you’re still left with “work with your DM”.

Comment: I think my issue of having to "multiclass into bard up to level 5" is less that I want it before level 5, but that's 5 levels in a different class I don't want to have to invest in. You mentioned "there is already an existing character option that adds it to the warlock spell list, and one that lets you cast it at will." What is this option? Ctrl+F on the dndbeyond page for warlocks doesn't show anything. There ar either spells available at will via invocations though, did you mean one of those would be equivalent?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage he's referring to the deep gnome feature that he mentioned previously. He's just saying that the balancing isn't a problem, because *for this spell*, there's a precedent for casting it "more times in a day than other classes do".

Comment: @AncientSwordRage The Svirfneblin Magic feat let’s you cast it at will, and you can take it at 4th level, if you are a deep gnome.

Comment: Ahhh right. I read that sentence "there is already an existing character option that adds it to the warlock spell list, and (that) one (is one) that lets you cast it at will." as refering to one spell not two. My bad. Need more coffee.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Seems like a pretty complete answer, I upvoted it early on. My preferred solution (from both a player and a DM viewpoint) is to just add it to the spell list for warlocks. Sometimes people just downvote without reason. *shrug*

Answer (score 20):

### Get an *Amulet of Proof Against Detection and Location* instead

The description of the [*Amulet of Proof Against Detection and Location*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/amulet-of-proof-against-detection-and-location) says (DMG, p. 150):

> *Wondrous Item, uncommon (requires attunement)*
>
> While wearing this amulet, you are hidden from divination magic. You
> can't be targeted by such magic or perceived through magical scrying
> sensors.

This magic item does the same thing as the *nondetection* spell, although it only works for your character, but that appears to work with your character design.

As there are no level restrictions on magic items - and, other than attunement, no restrictions at all on this item) - it can be acquired at level 1.

This option lets you remain within RAW without changing your race or background (if working within RAW is important to you), but still requires working with your DM, as they decide which and when magic items are available to you.

Comment: The notable drawback here is that the item requires attunement.